# What is the technically correct meaning of a 'nested IF statement'?

Tags: python, language-agnostic

A very quick (and hopefully easy) question.

A colleague and I had a disagreement when discussing a nested IF statement. I assumed that it meant the IF statement was nested in another control structure/statement (e.g. a FOR loop, IF statement, CASE statement etc). My colleague thought it meant the IF statement needed to be nested in another IF statement.

Which of us is correct and why (might not be easy to answer)?

Comment: Your colleague is correct

Answer (score 3):

Your colleague is correct.

Nesting if statements refers to the logic tree thats gets created by adding branches, its location within the rest of your code bears no interest to this.

Similarly, the following wouldn't be a nested if because its creating a seperate logic tree within the for loop.

```
if i:
   for x in i:
      if x:
```

Answer (score 1):

nested "if" statements means it's one after the other, for instance:

```js
if(shouldLogin) {
    if(isUser) {
        if(userIsAdmin) {
           console.log('some code')
         }
   }
}
```

Ideally, depending on the situation, you'd want only 1 if:

`if (shouldLogin && isUser && userIsAdmin)`

Not a great example but hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

A nested if statement means that it is one after another, just like nested for loop (maybe you are more familiar with that).

A nested if statement looks like this:

```
if some condition:
   if something:
      # do something
```

Just like a nested for loop:

```
for i in something:
   for some in something:
      # do something
```

Comment: The op is asking if `for i in something: if i:` is a nested if statement

Answer (score 0):

In a nested if construct, you can have an if...elif...else construct inside another if...elif...else construct.

```
if statement:
    if another_statement:
        do_something()
    else:
        do_another_thing()
elif not statement:
    if another_statement:
        do_something()
    else:
        do_another_thing() 
else:
    yet_nother_func()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to make you answer as simple as possible and focus on the topic the OP has asked for. Comparing with boolean constants ("foo is True", "bar is False") makes the code unnecessarily complicated. What you want to explain could as well be expressed with `if statement:` `if not another_statement:` etc...